# Hare and Tortoise printing out same output

Tags: c, function, loops

I am new to C and am trying out the well-known Hare and Tortoise assignment. I keep on getting the same problem where it is the same output for when the Hare wins and it will print out. I have a feeling that my problem might be in my display() function but im not really sure where I went wrong. Thank You

```
H 
TORTOISE WINS!!! YAY!!!
```

when the Tortoise wins.

This is my code that i currently have.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>

int moveTortoise(int* t);
int moveHare(int* h);
void display (int *t, int *h);

int main()
{
    printf("BANG!!!!!\nAND THEY'RE OFF!!!!!");
    int t, h = 1;
    while(t != 70 && h != 70)
    {
        moveTortoise(&t);
        moveHare(&h);
        display(&t,&h);

    }
    if(t > h)
        printf("TORTOISE WINS!!! YAY!!!");
    else if(h > t)
        printf("HARE WINS. YUCH.");
    else
        printf("IT'S A TIE");

    return 0;
}

int moveTortoise(int *t)
{
    int i = ((rand() % 10) + 1);
    if(i >= 1 && i <= 5) // fast plod
    {
        *t += 3;
    }
    else if(i >= 6 && i <= 7) // slip
    {
        *t -= 6;
    }
    else if(i >= 8 && i <= 10) // slow plod
    {
        *t += 1;
    }

    if(*t < 1)
        *t = 1;
    else if(*t > 70)
        *t = 70;
}
int moveHare(int *h)
{
    int i = ((rand() % 10) + 1);

    if( i >= 1 && i <= 2) // no move
    {
        *h = *h;
    }
    else if( i >= 3 && i <= 4) // big hop
    {
        *h += 9;
    }
    else if( i == 5) // big slip
    {
        *h += 12;
    }
    else if( i >= 6 && i <= 8) //small hop
    {
        *h += 1;
    }
    else if( i >= 9 && i <= 10) // small slip
    {
        *h -= 2;
    }

    if(*h < 1)
        *h = 1;
    else if(*h > 70)
        *h = 70;

}
void display(int *t,int *h)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 70; i++)
    {
        if( i == *t) 
            printf("T\n");
        else if( i == *h)
            printf("H\n");
        else if( i == *t == *h)
            printf("OUCH!!!");

    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't initialize `t`

Comment: in moveHare function, don't do:
    *h = *h;
Why this?
Just remove the "if", if you don't move.

Comment: The hare's "big slip" looks more like an extra big hop than a slip.  You add 12; a slip implies subtracting 12.

Comment: @StoryTeller i did that but now the Hare always wins with the same output every time.

Comment: Means you need to [debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: regarding: `else if( i == *t == *h)`  this will cause the compiler to output a warning message.  Suggest: `else if( i == *t && *t == *h)

Comment: regarding: `int t, h = 1;`  the variable `t` will contain what ever trash is on the stack at the location of the variable.  Also for ease of readability and understanding, follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  Suggest: `int t = 1; int h = 1;`

Comment: before calling `rand()` for the first time, need to call `srand()` to set a 'seed' into the random number generator.  Suggest in function: `main()` before the `while()` loop insert `srand( (unsigned)time( void ) );`   which, of course, means also need the header file: `time.h`

Comment: the signature of the `moveTortoise()` function states that the returned type is `int`, however, there is no `return value;` statement in that function. Suggest changing the signature to: `void moveTortoise( int *t )`   Similar considerations exist for the `moveHare()` function.

Comment: regarding the function: `void display(int *t,int *h)`  Since the parameter, dereferenced, values are not being changed, why pass pointer.  Could just as easily pass the values.  This would take a minor tweak in the calls to to that function, the prototype for that function, and in the body of the function. However, all those tweaks are very easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to seed the random number generator differently on each run to avoid getting the same sequence of random numbers on each execution (see `srand`). Time and/or process ID should suffice for this exercise.
Also, initialise `t` (as mentioned in the comments above).
Finally and your third comparison in `display` will trigger at the wrong time because it evaluates as `if ((i == *t) == *h)`; use `i == *t && i == *h` instead.